# Application updating functionality in sencha touch

Tags: android, web-applications, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha touch. I am working on a project where i need to check for update if any available. If the update is available then we should provide the way to update the application which will full new version of the application. My question is how we can check for update and if update is available then we need to update the application with user acceptance.

Note:- Here we are using own server not market or appstore. So through api call we can check for the update. `But after getting the update information how to allow user to update the application without any extra glitches not able to get an idea. Please help me out to overcome with this problem`.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the onUpdated function in your app.js